# how do I group records in angularjs on the basis of mysql database records

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

Here is static code for displaying group by team in html page. 
I want the same process using mysql database records. What changes are required in anuglar controller and Api

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(team, players) in teamPlayers | groupBy:'team'">
        {{team}}
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="player in players">
                {{player.name}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope) {
    var teamAlpha = {name: 'team alpha'};
    var teamBeta = {name: 'team beta'};
    var teamGamma = {name: 'team gamma'};

    $scope.teamPlayers = [{name: 'Gene', team: teamAlpha},
                      {name: 'George', team: teamBeta},
                      {name: 'Steve', team: teamGamma},
                      {name: 'Paula', team: teamBeta},
                      {name: 'Scruath of the 5th sector', team: teamGamma}];
});
```

**Php Code**

```
$select=" select name, team from player where 1";
$result=$con->query($select)or die(mysqli_error());
$num=$result->num_rows;
if($num > 0)
{
    $arr = array(); 
    while($row=$result->fetch_array())
    {
    $arr[]=array('name'=>$row['name'], 
                    'team'=>$row['team'],

                    );  

        }

    }

$outputArr = array();
$outputArr['Player'] = $arr;
header("Content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode($outputArr);
```

Comment: Do you have an existing back-end service that returns team players or players with team ?

Comment: @ Abbé Résina I have backend in my local server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a backend service at `http::localhost/myapi/players` that returns a list of players with their team, i.e.

```
[{name: 'Gene', team: { name: 'team alpha'}},
 {name: 'George', team: {name: 'team beta'}},
 ...];
```

You can use angular `$http` service to call the backend like this:

```
app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    var playerUrl = 'http::localhost/myapi/players';
    $http.get(playerUrl).then(function(response) {
        $scope.teamPlayers = response.data;
    }, function(responseError) {
        // do something if backend return an error
    });
});
```

As a good practice, you can put the server calls in a separate service, for instance if you have several views&controllers that shall call the same service, e.g.

```
app.factory('teamService', ['$http', function($http) {
    var playerUrl = 'http::localhost/myapi/players';        
    return {
        getTeamPlayers: function() {
            return $http.get(playerUrl);
        }
    }
}]);
```

then your controller is:

```
app.controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', 'teamService', function($scope, teamService) {
    teamService.getTeamPlayers().then(function(response) {
        $scope.teamPlayers = response.data;
    }, function(responseError) {
        // do something if backend return an error
    });
}]);
```

`$http` service is asynchronous and returns a `promise` hence the use of `.then(function(response) {...});`. See [$http documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) for details.

Note:
You have to set the dependency on [angular.filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter) for the `groupBy` filter, and you should group by `team.name` not only `team`.

I setup a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/CShMORHyf30B0jwzQ1Xc?p=preview) where the backend service is hardcoded.

Comment: Thanks alot @Abbe Resina

Answer (score 0):

Controller:

```
var teamAlpha = {name: 'team alpha'};
var teamBeta = {name: 'team beta'};
var teamGamma = {name: 'team gamma'};

$scope.teamPlayers = [{name: 'Gene', team: teamAlpha},
                  {name: 'George', team: teamBeta},
                  {name: 'Steve', team: teamGamma},
                  {name: 'Paula', team: teamBeta},
                  {name: 'Scruath of the 5th sector', team: teamGamma}];
```

view:

```
<ul ng-repeat="(team, value) in teamPlayers | groupBy: 'team.name'">
  Group name: {{ team }}
  <li ng-repeat="player in value">
    player: {{ player.name }} 
  </li>
</ul>
```

this is a demo http://jsbin.com/qobasocido/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: what will the code in my angular controller while getting data from php .